Почему у меня не работает мой парсер на Scrapy?
Данные должны сохраняться в json файл, но ничего не происходит и создается просто пустой файл. В чем моя ошибка? В settings установлено DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3 и ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
Вот мой код
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider


class WildberriesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'wildberriesSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.wildberries.ru']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/elektronika/noutbuki-pereferiya/noutbuki-ultrabuki?sort=popular&page=1'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css('article.product-card'):
            link = product.css('a.j-open-full-product-card::attr(href)').get()

            price = product.css('ins.price__lower-price::text').get()
            if price is not None:
                price = price.replace('\u00a0', '').replace('\u20bd', '').strip()

            yield {
                'link': link,
                'brand': product.css('span.product-card__brand::text').get().strip(),
                'name': product.css('span.product-card__name::text').get().strip(),
                'price': price
            }

            next_page = response.css('a.pagination-next::attr(href)').get()
            if next_page is not None:
                yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

